# Split Dataframe into Groups, then calculate Cumprod by Group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to split a Dataframe n groups, evenly with each group of size:

```
group_size = math.ceil(len(df)/n)
```

Then I want to calculate the cumprod for each group.

For example:

```
 Val - Group - Cumprod
  1  -   0   -    1
  3  -   0   -    3
  5  -   0   -    15
  2  -   1   -    2
  3  -   1   -    6
  ..     ..       ..
```

Appreciate any help on possible approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using Numpy to define grouping array

```
#            Number of Groups you want
#                         
a = np.arange(len(df)) * 2 // len(df)

df.assign(Cumprod=df.groupby(a).Val.cumprod())

   Val  Group  Cumprod
0    1      0        1
1    3      0        3
2    5      0       15
3    2      1        2
4    3      1        6
```

Comment: note that `np.arange()` method above is 100 times faster than `pd.cut()` which in turn is about 20 % faster than `pd.qcut()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `qcut` and `cumprod`:

```
n = 2
df['cut'] = pd.qcut(df.index,n,labels=range(n))
df['cumprod'] = df.groupby('cut')['values'].cumprod()
```

Comment: Why not: `pd.cut(df.index, n, labels=range(n))`?

Comment: `transform` is not necessary